# Failing to write bytes in file

Tags: java, android, android-file

I have created a file and I want to write in bytes in this file but it's not working. Where is the problem?

```
public void writeFileExternalStorage() {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "hhh.txt");
    try {
        if(!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outputStream ;
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        outputStream.write(files.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: can you share your error? did you add permission ? did you grant permission runtime?

Comment: you might want to paste the crash log or explain what is wrong -"It's not working" is not a good description of the problem. Otherwise, just read up on the method from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE yes i have

Comment: There is no error, only the file ( hhh.txt ) is not there

Comment: it might be because you surrounded your code in a try-catch. please check if your code goes to catch phrase or not. if so, you could see the error

Comment: please add logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `createNewFile` call will return `true` if it has successfully created the file.  You should check the result of the call, and log an error if it is `false`.
2. According to the documentation for `getExternalFilesDir` ([javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))):

   > *[it m]ay return `null` if shared storage is not currently available.*

   If that happens you will call `new File(null, "hhh.txt")`.  That is equivalent to `new File("hhh.txt")` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-)), so the file would be created in the app's "current user directory".